# Testing different modules used with ImportError

Tags: importerror, fixtures, pytest

How can I run the same tests with different modules that are sometimes imported like this depending on availability:

```
    try:
        from gevent.local import local
    except ImportError:
        from threading import local
```

So, I would like the same tests to run once with gevent.local and again with threading, just to make sure my code really works with both modules.

I suspect that fixtures might be useful but I'm not sure how the modules should be made available or not within those fixtures. This problem has most likely been solved before so I searched stackoverflow for keywords like pytest and ImportEror. I couldn't find anything among all the other unrelated ImportError questions so assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: why you don't try to import both modules in try body?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with just py.test.  Probably the current answer is to solve this using tox and define two environments: one with gevent installed and one without.